# TableViewController with searchBar first search slow

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitableview

I am working on a simple **TableViewController** application with a connected **sqlite db**. Unfortunately the **first search (via the search bar) is kind of slow**, but only during the first invocation. Everything runs smooth after the first query, even if I close the app and reopen it - still smooth.

If I quit it via the "ios task manager" and reopen it, the first search is slow again.

I think it's not up to the database cause the ongoing queries are ok. I guess it has sth. to do with the cells or the initialization of sth. in the tableview. At the moment I am using a nib file for the cells. Then I changed it to a programmatical way of using cells - still no change.

If I start the application with a starting "select * from .." and show the result, then the following search is smooth too.

Does anyone have any comments for this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I will look in the way you connect to database, because the problem is only on first search. You also can log your methods to examine which method cost you so expensive. Example

```
NSLog(@"%f",[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000);
```

at the beginning and the end of every method.

Comment: Hi, I already did that. I first thought it was the db too but if I just start any query (in code e.g. select *) but don't update the tableview - its still slow. If I start a query and update the tableview at the beginning the ongoing searches are quick.

Comment: You 're right. I found the bottleneck. It is the call to sqlite3_prepare_v2 . If I do it with a query when the program starts, its running smoothly. I always sqlite3_finalize the stmt after a query. So, is sqlite3_prepare_v2 reusing the query although I finalized it?

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was because of the tableview that was loading cells from a array.

i made a "fake load"

```
tableView.hidden = YES;

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    array addObject..
} 

[tableView reloadData];
```

then after 0.1 sec

```
[array removeAllObjects];
[tableView reloadData];

tableView.hidden = NO;
```